# FirebaseAuthWithPlayGames Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Given String is empty or null

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-play-games

Hello I have a fully working code for signing in a Player by Google Play Games Sign in. See this code snippet

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestServerAuthCode("720182182679-fv285c7k5kecqhqdmc9ggc9f73jc9hef.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(start.this, gso);


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();




 private void startSignInIntent() {
    GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    Intent intent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            // The signed in account is stored in the result.
            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
            assert signedInAccount != null;
            Toast.makeText(start.this, "Google Play Games Connectet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The code above works perfektly. But if I want to trigger the following method the game crashes, and gets me the error in the title.

```
private void firebaseAuthWithPlayGames(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithPlayGames:" + acct.getId());
    AuthCredential credential = PlayGamesAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getServerAuthCode());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(start.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                }

                // ...
            });
}
```

I trigger this method by calling it in the on ActivityResult of startSignInIntent like this:

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            // The signed in account is stored in the result.
            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
            assert signedInAccount != null;
   --------->   firebaseAuthWithPlayGames(signedInAccount);   <-----------
            Toast.makeText(start.this, "Google Play Games Connectet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone has faced this issue and can help.

Comment: It is better to put this code inside the onConnected.  But having said that, I am getting the same error.  The following line returns null    AuthCredential credential = 
          PlayGamesAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getServerAuthCode());

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because it is not getting the token correctly between Game Services and Firebase

You have to configure the web app that is linked to the same game in the play console. Then copy the client id from the web app and paste it into the setup dialog for the plugin.

Steps are here...
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/play-games

Double check these steps:

Enable Google Play Games as a sign-in provider:

Find your project's web server client ID and client secret. The web server client ID identifies your Firebase project to the Google Play auth servers.

To find these values:

Open your Firebase project in the Google APIs console credentials page.
In the OAuth 2.0 client IDs section, open the Web client (auto created by Google Service) details page. This page lists your web server client ID and secret.
Then, in the Firebase console, open the Authentication section.

On the Sign in method tab, enable the Play Games sign-in provider. You will need to specify your project's web server client ID and client secret, which you got from the APIs console.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have just bumped into the exact same issue you have experienced earlier. I see, already 1 year have passed since your question, but I hope maybe it still can help you or others.

I was doing the integration of Firebase with my existing game that had Google Play Games Services. I wanted Firebase to use Play Games authentication, but after I have done everything according to the manual, the sign-in into Firebase was unsuccessful with the error message: **Given String is empty or null**.

I have figured out that actually there was no problem with the code, nor with the integration setup. **The solution was that simply I had to log out from my Google account and re-login again.**

I think, at the time when I last logged in to my Google account and Games Services in my app, the info about the Firebase integration setup was not existing there yet, so my cached account on my phone did not know about it at all. The re-login refreshed the settings in the cache and the following authCode request could finally successfully return the needed string:

```
String authCode = signedInAccount.getServerAuthCode();
```